# Problems with Id at the end of a restful api

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

The fetch works if I just use the URL without /"some ID" at the end, but I want to target a sepcific id. I think the problem is from the clientside, because `router.patch()` works with postman (using the same URL). However I am not able to send any data to the server because the fetch cant find the URL (404). Or maybe fetch doesent work with patch requests, idk?

client-side:

```
 async function update(){
    const fromInp = { username: inp.value }; 
    let param = {
        method: 'PUT', // or 'POST'
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(fromInp),
    }

     await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/userModel/5e4ec9567566adade97df11e`, param)

}
```

server-side:

```
     router.patch('/:postId', async (req,res)=>{
                try{
                    const update = await User.updateOne(
                        {_id: req.params.postId},
                        { $set: {username: req.body.username}}) 
                    res.json(update)
                } catch(err){
                    res.json({message: err})
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the method property to be the text: `'PATCH'`.